# How can i generate a java class from a nexus repository using JAXB

Tags: java, maven, xsd, jaxb

I have two projects:

A/ JAR artifact where the schema.xsd is located

B/ src/main/gen pom.xml

I want in B project generate classes from XSD, that exists in A Project where the jar file is located on a nexus repository.

Here is how look my pom.xml from project B

```
<plugin>
      <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.0</version>
      <executions>
          <execution>
              <goals>
                  <goal>generate</goal>
              </goals>
          </execution>
      </executions>
      <configuration>
          <schemas>
              <schema>
                  <dependencyResource>
                      <groupId>project.A</groupId>
                      <artifactId>A</artifactId>
                      <version>${project.version}</version>
                      <resource>test.xsd</resource>
                  </dependencyResource>
              </schema>
          </schemas>
          <generateDirectory>../test_class/src/main/java</generateDirectory>
          <generatePackage>mypackage</generatePackage>
      </configuration>
</plugin>
```

It generate correctly a java class into the project B from the xsd schema because project A is stored on my local repository.

But I have no idea on : How to generate a java class from a nexus repository?

Comment: It does not matter where your artifact is located as you specified it as a dependency. Same with "normal" maven dependencies which are also downloadable from a artifact store if not present locally - at least, when the artifact store is configured in the POM (under the `<repositories>` part).

Comment: Oh ok I didn't know it work like that. A strange thing is that when i delete the project A from my local repository it doesn't download it from the nexus and it didn't find the dependency..

Comment: How did the original artifact containing A appear in your local repository?

Comment: When i launch the mvn clean install command in project A.

Ok i managed to solve it, the repositories wasn't configure well! It works now thanks you for you help